# Помощь с копированием элементов в массиве

Tags: javascript

Как взять пару элементов с конца массива с помощью slice?

Есть допустим массив, который я использую в цикле. И мне надо на каждой итерации копировать часть массива, но с конца. К примеру, когда `i = 0` мне нужно скопировать часть массива с конца [20,`10,30,10,10,15,35]` только эту часть, до `i(20)` И так далее: `i = 1` - копирую [20,10,`30,10,10,15,35]` до `i`.
Не могу правильно написать от и до.

```js
arr = [20,10,30,10,10,15,35]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Видимо должно быть:

от "i"  до "длинаМассива - i + 1"

С конца отрезается за счет знака минус (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

то есть будет примерно так

```
arr.slice(-(длинаМассива - i + 1));
```

Comment: Спасибо. Получилось если брать так (-arr.length + i+1) . Через минус

Comment: Да, хотел как раз это дописать

Comment: Мда, решил задачу и только сейчас понял, что не обязательно было идти с конца. Можно было просто от i+1, и до конца.. 
Тупишь так по 2 часа, и в итоге все просто.